# Mobile Friendly Alternative to Tables?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm learning HTML/CSS and I want to rewrite the site listed below (currently made with Windows Excel) to something custom written by me. The problem is that working with tables is kind of tough going mobile friendly. I haven't gotten' into Javascript yet (soon) but is there a CSS way to take care of this?

Site I want to change: http://libertyresourcedirectory.com/d/home.html

For this site: http://eglove.github.io/ I use @media screen only max-width 1024px and 728px to give an automatic "tablet" and "mobile" version. Doing it with the LRD site would not break up the tables properly.

Thanks in advance for any answers! :)

Comment: You can use divs with `display:table`.

Comment: For responsiveness, DIVs should replace your tables for structure

Comment: Also, please include at last snippets of your code in the question. Links the the actual live pages don't work well because they will be updated/removed and unavailable for later reference.

Comment: Thanks jacelysh, I'll make sure to compare display:table and the div inline solution below. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this: [http://jsfiddle.net/sGJW5/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/sGJW5/)
HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
       <li>
           Computers
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Editing</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Internet/Privacy </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <ul>
       <li>
           Computers
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Editing</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Internet/Privacy </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container
{
    display:inline-block;
}

.container ul
{
    list-style:none;
}

.container ul li:first-child
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll try this out (can't right now) and the display:table just to play with the options. But this makes sense and I appreciate it. :)